# Table creation from CSV file with header

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, sqoop

I want to import a large csv file with headers (100+ columns) into MySQL without creating the table manually.

I am ready to use any tools from MySQL workbench to Sqoop or any other Hadoop tool.

Have tried searching for a solution but didn't find any proper answer (or) answers were too old saying it's not possible.

Comment: Look into using MySQL's `LOAD DATA` command [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).  It has the ability to very rapidly import large amounts of CSV data directly into a table.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest and Quickest way I found to create a large table (100+ columns) in MySQL is by using MySQL Workbench:

1. Create new schema
2. Right click on Tables -> Table Data Import Wizard.
3. Select your CSV file with header included.
4. Cross check the type of column, If needed change column type and name.
5. Click Import to create table and import data.

If want to load data manually:

`load data infile '/filepath/filename.csv' into table tablename_table fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n'` `(` `col1`,`col2`,`coln` `);`

Column list can be taken from the create command generated by the MySQL Workbench.